# What level packs are available for LittleBigPlanet?

Tags: little-big-planet

Are there any additional level packs available for LittleBigPlanet?  There seems to be an endless array of costume packs.  I've downloaded the Metal Gear Solid and Pirates of the Caribbean levels, but that's only because I knew about them and was looking.  I can't seem to find anywhere that lists any additional packs that include levels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LBP considers stickers also new level pieces, so I'm not sure if you want to count those or not. I've listed the ones that come with new level assets such as objects/sounds instead of just stickers. Packs that only have new costumes and stickers are not included on this list. If you want stickers included, I'll edit that in later.

This list includes packs that came with new level pieces, and are still as of this posting available (doesn't include stuff like Beta Tester only things or limited time offers).

As of September 2010, the packs which include new content for level creation that are available for download are:

- [Creator Pack 1](http://www.mediamolecule.com/blog/article/out_now_heavenly_sword_pack_and_creator_pack_1/)
- [Festive Level Pack](http://www.1up.com/news/festive-level-pack-coming-big)
- [History Pack](http://www.mediamolecule.com/blog/article/history_in_the_making/)
- [The Incredibles Level Kit](http://www.littlebigplanet.com/en-gb/game_guide/ps3/downloadable_content/the_incredibles_level_kit/)
- [Marvel Level Pack](http://marvel.com/news/vgstories.12963.marvel~apos~s_little_big_planet_dlc_details)
- [Monsters Kit](http://www.mediamolecule.com/blog/article/run_and_hide_here_come_the_monsters/)
- [Music Pack](http://www.mediamolecule.com/blog/article/this_week_mm_music_pack_1/) - Only 3 music tracks
- [Team ICO Pack](http://www.mediamolecule.com/blog/article/store_update_team_ico_pack/) - has some new sound effects

You can find the full list of DLC [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_LittleBigPlanet_downloadable_content_packs).

Comment: I'm just looking for level packs, not packs that only contain costumes/stickers/objects. It looks like there are three: Metal Gear Solid, Marvel, and Pirates of the Caribbean.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are referring to packs containing complete levels that were created by Media Molecule themselves, in which case I believe the two you mentioned are the only ones there are.